# Retrieving Device Context from .NET print API

Tags: c#, .net, printing, pinvoke

I am working on a .NET application to control DataCard Desktop Card printers, and I have stumbled upon a problem. In order to execute Magnetic Stripe and Chip encoding, I have to call a function in a native printer API dll to enable the printers Interactive mode.

I have managed to create the P/Invoke code to call this native function. But the problem is that this method takes the printer Device Context handle as a parameter, and have to be called BEFORE the Gdi32 StartDoc function is called.

In the .NET printing API I do have access to the hDC from the Graphics object. But as far as I can see the Graphics object is only availible AFTER the StartDoc function is invoked.

So my question is if anyone knows a way to retrieve the context before StartDoc is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `OpenPrinter` to retrieve a printer handle (`HANDLE`) and then call `CreateDC` by passing in this handle to get a printer DC anytime (before `StartDoc`).

Comment: I assume you mean the "winspool.drv" and "gdi32.dll" functions? I am aware that this is not difficult to do using the native C apis. But my application is a .NET application, so I would hope I could use the .NET api as far as possible.

Comment: You are already using P/Invoke which is why I ventured this reply. Mention your needs clearly in the question.

Comment: I think I clearly mentioned that my problem was with the .NET printing API. However writing my own p/invoke wrapper for Gdi32 seems to be the only way to achieve this.