# pass the data to printer as a raw data

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zebra-printers

I am working with a zebra printer that is defined as default printer on my machine.

I want to pass to the zebra driver all the information as a raw information, tell the printer driver not to encode anything going to the printer, but to pass it along unchanged.

I want to use `PrintDocument`, is this possible?

Or would you suggest something else?

Comment: Can you give an example of the API? For instance, if the SDK uses C or C++ can you post an example?

Comment: With Zebra printers, I found using ZPL to be the easiest approach.

Comment: @Austin Salonen: How i can deal with zebra that connected as default printer , How i can send my data to is after i have formated it in ZPL format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending raw data to FedEx Label printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123154/sending-raw-data-to-fedex-label-printer)

Comment: FTP is the quickest implementation, IMO (FTP a ZPL file to the printer).  With a socket approach, you can stream the ZPL but it's not as easy as the FTP approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the "Advanced Setup" tab of the Zebra printer driver, you can "Enable Passthrough Mode". Then, just ensure that your stream starts with `${` and ends with `}$`  Then the driver will not do anything to the stuff inbetween the `${` `}$`

Comment: Did this really work using .NET? (I assume that's what `PrintDocument` is part of.) I thought .NET straight-out didn't support printer fonts, because it rendered everything into a graphic when printing. For passthrough mode to work, you need to use a printer font.

Comment: The Zebra driver has an option to pass thru all the data without converting it to a bitmap. If you use just a generic printer driver, you won't get this functionality

Comment: Does that passthrough option work *if the text is in a TrueType font*, or does it need to be in a printer font? I use the Zebra Designer driver.

Comment: The question wasn't about fonts, just passing data to the printer thru the driver without any kind of windows/driver conversion magic. If you want to use a TrueType font on the printer, you would have to use the Font and Graphics downloader to download your font on the printer, and then pass thru ZPL to use that font in your format

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want to pass through ZPL commands to the printer, but my application can only print using TrueType fonts. I can't get passthrough to work. I thought this was because passthrough wouldn't work with TrueType, and .NET can't support anything else: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6545&pmv=print&impressions=false http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783873/how-do-i-access-printer-specific-fonts-in-net

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, going through the Windows print drivers was overly complicated for Zebra printers.  If you can build up the ZPL, there are two options (one *real* easy and the other slightly complicated):

1. Save the ZPL to a file and FTP it to the printer.
2. Stream the ZPL to the printer via sockets.

I've done both in the past and, as far as I know, both systems are still running without issue.

Comment: If my Zebra connected to the computer via usb and defined as default printer , I am not sure that it has a IP address for uploading via ftp.

Comment: I believe you can copy a file to LPT

Comment: But i connected via USB connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just print any raw data to zebra printer. The printer will only recognize commands that are  supported by the printer languages ie: ZPL, EPL or both in some models.

Printdocument is possible provided one of the above mentioned codes are written in the text file that you are sending to the printer. Eg.:

```
^XA
^FO50,50
^A0N,30,30^FDTEST PRINT^FS
^XZ
```

Save these commands in notepad and save it as, lets say, "test.txt".
Now you can print this document directly to the printer by executing following DOS command (assuming the printer is connected via LPT2 port)

Open a DOS prompt and type:

```
copy test.txt lpt2
```

If the printer is connected via a USB port, install "Generic / Text Only" printer (available in Windows by default) and then open the notepad and print to Generic / Text Only printer.